# KKT stationarity condition in simple SDP

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

This question is part of my continuing efforts to answer my original question in [A puzzling KKT for LMI vs. scalar constraint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4028018/a-puzzling-kkt-for-lmi-vs-scalar-constraint).

Consider an SDP
\begin{align}
&\min  - \text{Tr}(P)\\
&\ \ \text{s.t.} 
\begin{pmatrix}
A^TP + PA +C^TPC + Q & PB + C^TPD \\
B^T P + D^TPC& R+D^TPD
\end{pmatrix}\succeq0, P\succeq0
\end{align}

In a paper, they define a dual variable as
\begin{align}
Z= \begin{pmatrix}  
S&U^T&0\\
U&T&0\\
0&0&W
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
and claim that
\begin{align}
AS+SA^T + CSC^T + BU + DUC^T + U^TB^T + CU^TD^T + D^TTD + W + I=0.
\end{align}
By computing the KKT stationarity condition, we get that the Trace of this equation is zero rather than its argument. What am I missing?

I will be happy for help about this step and two more related questions:

1. How will the equation change if we change to objective to $-\text{Tr}(R+D^TPD)$.
2. Is it a standard SDP? I learned that the objective should be expressed as $c^Tx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the primal as:
\begin{align}
&\min  - \text{Tr}(P)\\
&\ \ \text{s.t.} 
\begin{pmatrix}
A^TP + PA +C^TPC + Q & PB + C^TPD & 0 \\
B^T P + D^TPC& R+D^TPD & 0 \\
0 & 0 & P
\end{pmatrix}\succeq0
\end{align}
The Lagrangian is:
\begin{align}
L(P,Z) = - \text{Tr}(P) - \langle 
\begin{pmatrix}
A^TP + PA +C^TPC + Q & PB + C^TPD & 0 \\
B^T P + D^TPC& R+D^TPD & 0 \\
0 & 0 & P
\end{pmatrix} , Z \rangle
\end{align}
If you take the derivative with respect to $P$ you obtain the stationarity condition:
\begin{align}
0&=\frac{\partial L(P,Z)}{\partial P}\\
&=  - \frac{\partial}{\partial P} \left\{\text{Tr}(P) + \text{Tr} \left(S^T(A^TP+PA + C^TPC+Q) + U(PB+C^TPD))\right)\right\}\\
&\ \ \ \ \  - \frac{\partial}{\partial P} \left\{ \text{Tr}\left(U^T(B^TP+D^TPC) + T^T(R+D^TPD) + P^TW)\right)\right\}.
\end{align}
By using the general relation $\frac{\partial}{\partial P} \text{Tr}(\Gamma P \Lambda) = \frac{\partial}{\partial P} \text{Tr}(\Lambda\Gamma P ) = \Lambda^T\Gamma^T$ for any $\Lambda,\Gamma$ and the cyclic trace property, we get:
\begin{align}
0&= I + AS + SA^T + CSC^T + U^TB^T + CU^TD^T + BU + DUC^T + DTD^T+ W.
\end{align}

As for your other questions:

1. the $I$ at the end will become $DD^T$
2. there is no 'standard' SDP, but an SDP in standard form is:
   $$\min_{X \succeq O} \{ \text{Tr}(CX) : \text{Tr}(A_iX)=b_i, \; i=1,\ldots,m\}$$
   so clearly the given SDP is not in standard form. You can always reformulate it into standard form though (using a different choice for $X$).

Comment: @Morad $\langle A,B \rangle = \text{Tr}(A^TB)$, not $\text{Tr}(AB)$

Comment: @Morad I have updated the derivation and found discrepancies in the terms $CSC^T$ and in $DTD^T$

Comment: Correct, there was a typo in the first entry and I corrected it to $C^TPC$. The $DTD^T$ term does not have a typo however. I noticed the inner product typo, but some reviewers did not approve my second edit.

Comment: For the inner product, $A$ is symmetric, no?

Comment: @Morad not necessarily, it is a valid inner product on the set of all (including asymmetric) matrices

Comment: For the general case, I agree. In our case here the corresponding matrix A is symmetric so replacing $A^T$ with $A$ will not change the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120172/discussion-between-morad-and-linalg).